# Uso della virgola prima di "ma"

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions

In questo [sito web](http://grammatica-italiana.dossier.net/punteggiatura.htm) ho letto:

> Prima di 'ma', la virgola può essere presente o mancante, a seconda della struttura logica del discorso e degli effetti stilistici ricercati.

Potreste spiegarmi questa affermazione? Quando si deve mettere e quando non si deve mettere la virgola prima di "ma"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Secondo me la risposta dipende molto dalla sensibilità di chi risponde, non ci sono regole precise. Se metti la virgola, vuol dire che vuoi indicare un piccolo stacco nella frase. Se non la metti, vuol dire che la frase deve essere pronunciata tutta insieme. Questo in alcuni casi può spostare leggermente quale parte della frase vuoi evidenziare maggiormente.

Per esempio, se confronto le due frasi:

> Sarei venuto a trovarti ma pioveva troppo.
>
> Sarei venuto a trovarti, ma pioveva troppo.

Nel secondo caso c'è un'evidenza leggermente maggiore sulla principale, mentre nel secondo c'è un'evidenza leggermente maggiore sulla subordinata. Però la differenza è veramente lieve.

A parte questo, direi che tendenzialmente se si è indecisi o no sulla virgola prima del "ma", allora è meglio metterla. Questo è particolarmente vero nei periodi lunghi, perché la presenza della virgola aiuta maggiormente a scandire la lettura.

Answer (score -1):

Quando il 'ma' introduce una specificazione inessenziale per la comprensione della proposizione principale usa la virgola, altrimenti no.

Questo è tutto.

Comment: Signor downvoter, sarebbe gradito sapere cosa è sbagliato nella risposta. Grazie.

Comment: Non ho votato, ma posso dirti perché c'è il voto negativo: la risposta non dice quasi nulla.